# What are the possible reasons for signal 11 on destructor call?

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have the following loop ( this happens when an array of 24 objects of type SgApp is deleted with delete[] )

```
   0x086f5361 <+45>:    cmp    ebx,DWORD PTR [esi+0x4]
   0x086f5364 <+48>:    je     0x86f5375 <PSM::~PSM()+65>
   0x086f5366 <+50>:    sub    ebx,0xd4
   0x086f536c <+56>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebx]
   0x086f536e <+58>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],ebx
=> 0x086f5371 <+61>:    call   DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x086f5373 <+63>:    jmp    0x86f5361 <PSM::~PSM()+45>
```

In this code %ebx is acting like an iterator %esi points to the start of the array and sizeof(SgApp)=0xd4. At the start of the array the first 4 bytes represent the number 24.
Line `0x086f5371 <+61>: call   DWORD PTR [eax]` calls SgApp default virtual destructor.

1. From this code I understand that first DWORD of an object points to a vtable and the first DWORD from the vtable points to the destructor. Is this correct? This happens every time I have a virtual destructor?
2. Under what conditions this calling of the destructor will cause signal 11 seg fault at this exact line `0x086f5371 <+61>:    call   DWORD PTR [eax]`? My guess is that the value pointed by %eax is in some unallocated zone, but what are the possible reasons for this? At this point I should have all 24 objects of type SgApp ( they were created in the contructor ).

I mention that this signal 11 happened only once and all I got is a lousy core-dump. Under normal circumstances this is not reproducible, so I'm looking for every possible explanation, including maybe some hardware fault or some exotic scenario.

Comment: Can't you show the actual C++ code instead?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Unfortunately I cannot but basically in the PSM constructor I have `keys = new SgApp[24];` and in the PSM destructor I have `delete [] keys;` . Also there is no PSM object passed as value.

Comment: It could be that you are deleting an object that doesn't actually exist, so that `this` is most likely null or another invalid pointer in the destructor.

Comment: How does copy constructor and assignment operator look like? Is there any other code that modifies `keys` member variable or expose it to class users?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Indeed the copy constructor and assignment operator is not implemented ( this is not my design, In the code all parameters are not passed by value but just pointers ), but this is not a cause. If keys where to be deleted before the first 4 bytes would not represent 24 but -1 using gcc compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I will speculate that you are not following the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) and you end up with two or more objects pointing to the same dynamically allocated array. When their destructors get called, the second call results in an attempt to `delete []` something that has already been `delete[]`ed.

Comment: Indeed the copy constructor and assignment operator is not implemented ( this is not my design, In the code all parameters are not passed by value but just pointers ), but this is not a cause. If `keys` where to be deleted before the first 4 bytes would not represent 24 but -1 using gcc compiler. Edit: I have a core-dump and I can print some of the values, including the first 4 bytes of the array.